# Alias the main table's name in a Gorm query

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a Gorm query similar to:

```
db.
    Table(fmt.Sprintf("%s t", model.BlogTag{}.TableName())).
    Select(`
        t.id,
        t.path,
        t.title,
        t.hits,
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS used_times
    `).
    Joins("LEFT JOIN contentitem_tag_map bt ON bt.tag_id = t.id").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN content b ON b.id = bt.content_item_id AND b.state = 1").
    Where("t.published = 1").
    Group("t.id").
    Order("used_times DESC").
    Find(&tags).Error
```

The resulting query looks like:

```
SELECT t.id, t.path, t.title, t.hits, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS used_times
FROM `myschema`.`vk9wz_tags` 
LEFT JOIN myschema.vk9wz_contentitem_tag_map bt ON bt.tag_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN myschema.vk9wz_content b ON b.id = bt.content_item_id AND b.state = 1 
WHERE t.published = 1 
GROUP BY `t`.`id` 
ORDER BY used_times DESC
```

The alias `t` I tried to specify is not picked up by Gorm! Therefore MySQL doesn't understand what `t` is in first place.

The documentation doesn't include how to specify the table alias, as far as I can see.

Is there any way I can avoid using the full name in my query?

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NamingStrategy probably need to specify a custom return val for `JoinTableName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```golang
db.Table(model.BlogTag{}.TableName() + " AS t")
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining your answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "AS" was just missing in the questions table function to tie the table name to the alias and in addition to that using sprintf is just not necessary.